# send logs to multiple rsyslog servers

Tags: rsyslog

When I try to send data to multiple rsyslog servers, it is picking only the first forwarding rule and ignoring rest.

my rsyslog client conf file.

```
$WorkDirectory /var/tmp/rsyslog/work

$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /usr/local/abc/certs/syslog_ca.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls # use gtls netstream driver

### Forwarding rules #1
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # require TLS for the connection
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon # server is NOT authenticated
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # use asynchronous processing
$ActionQueueFileName srvrfwd  # set file name, also enables disk mode
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries on insert failure
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save in-memory data if rsyslog shuts down
if $syslogtag contains 'error' then @@rsyslog.abc.com:10514
& ~
###

### Forwarding rules #2
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # require TLS for the connection
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon # server is NOT authenticated
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # use asynchronous processing
$ActionQueueFileName srvrfwd1  # set file name, also enables disk mode
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries on insert failure
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save in-memory data if rsyslog shuts down
if $syslogtag contains 'error' then @@rsyslog1.abc.com:10514
& ~
###
```

if I comment forwading rule#1, it take rule#2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From rsyslog documentation : ( http://www.rsyslog.com/storing-messages-from-a-remote-system-into-a-specific-file/ )

> The next line (“& ~”) is important: it tells rsyslog to stop
>   processing the message after it was written to the log

So that (normaly) works :

```
$WorkDirectory /var/tmp/rsyslog/work

$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /usr/local/abc/certs/syslog_ca.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls # use gtls netstream driver

### Forwarding rules #1
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # require TLS for the connection
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon # server is NOT authenticated
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # use asynchronous processing
$ActionQueueFileName srvrfwd  # set file name, also enables disk mode
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries on insert failure
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save in-memory data if rsyslog shuts down
if $syslogtag contains 'error' then @@rsyslog.abc.com:10514
###

### Forwarding rules #2
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # require TLS for the connection
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon # server is NOT authenticated
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # use asynchronous processing
$ActionQueueFileName srvrfwd1  # set file name, also enables disk mode
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries on insert failure
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save in-memory data if rsyslog shuts down
if $syslogtag contains 'error' then @@rsyslog1.abc.com:10514
& ~
###
```

*Or Simply :*

```
$WorkDirectory /var/tmp/rsyslog/work

$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /usr/local/abc/certs/syslog_ca.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls # use gtls netstream driver

$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # require TLS for the connection
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon # server is NOT authenticated
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # use asynchronous processing
$ActionQueueFileName srvrfwd  # set file name, also enables disk mode
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries on insert failure
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save in-memory data if rsyslog shuts down
if $syslogtag contains 'error' then @@rsyslog.abc.com:10514
& @@rsyslog1.abc.com:10514
###
```